# asp:button ocmmandName disable post back

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

my website dynamically loads a data list with a dynamically loaded dropdownlist in each item.

My button inside of each item uses commandName to execute the code to take the value from the dropdownlist inside of the same item and do something with it. (by using the System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListCommandEventArgs e parameter)

My problem is, once you pick from the dropdownlist and click on the button, it performs a post-back and then takes the "currently selected value" from the ddl, which has now been reset to the first one because of post back...

How can I solve this?

I have tried putting OnClientClick="return false;" onto the button, but it seems to stop the commandName from running at all...

I have also tried UseSubmitBehavior="False", but it is not stopping the problem.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: In your page load, don't populate the drop down if its a post back. For example the first line is `if(IsPostBack) { return; }`

Comment: Where is the code being executed and where is your dropdown being bound? Make sure that it is not being rebound during postback, as this will cause you to lose the selected value. `Page.IsPostBack` will tell you if the current call to the page is a postback or not.